# Is there any way to define methods for data model when using FMPP?

Tags: fmpp

I want to add methods to my datamodel so I need a way to specify them inside my tdd data file(s).
For example having a tdd data file containing two scalars :

```
a: 1
b: 1
```

I would like to add a method `area` which multiplies them.
Is this even possible and if so how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you have `MyUtils` that has a `foo()` and a `bar()` methods, and you want to access those in the templates.

You can add an arbitrary Java objects to the model using the `eval` data loader in `data`, like `myUtils: eval('new com.example.MyUtils()')`. Then you can issue `myUtils.foo()` in the templates. But, you wanted to add the methods at top level. That's also possible. Both in `eval` and in a custom `DataLoader` (whichever you want to use) you have access to `engine`, the `fmpp.Engine` object. And then you can pull this trick:

```
// Note: In case you are using eval, use Java 1.2 syntax (no generics).
TemplateHashModel myUtilsModel = (TemplateHashModel) engine.wrap(new MyUtils());
Map<String, TemplateModel> myUtilsMethodModels = new HashMap<>();
myUtilsMethodModels.put("foo", myUtilsModel.get("foo"));
myUtilsMethodModels.put("bar", myUtilsModel.get("bar"));
return myUtilsMethodModels;
```

Then you add that `Map` to `data` *without a name*. (If you add a `Map` to `data` without a name, its keys become top-level variables.)

Certainly it can be polished to be nicer, like find methods you want automatically, etc. Plus I did not try this above (so typos are possible). But this is the basic idea. (I guess it would be practical if FMPP had a data loader that loads the static methods of a class... But, right now it doesn't have that.)